# How to ignore positive/negative lookbehind/lookahead groups in a regex?

Tags: java, regex

Is there a simple way to remove positive/negative lookbehind/lookahead groups from a regex expression using another regex expression (taking inside parenthesis into account)?

The example source expression: `A(?<!B(C)D)E(?<=F)G(?!H(I(J))K)L(?=M(O)P)Q(?>R)S(T)`
The parts I want removed:

- `(?<!B(C)D)`
- `(?<=F)`
- `(?!H(I(J))K)`
- `(?=M(O)P)`

So far, I made the expression `\(\?\<?[!=].+?\)` to find the parts to remove but the inside parenthesis creates problems... For example, instead of finding the part `(?<!B(C)D)`, it finds `(?<!B(C)`...

I thought about replacing the `(?<!`, `(?!`, `(?<=` & `(?=` with `(?#` (transforming them into embedded comment) and that works perfectly on "regex101.com" but sadly not in JAVA...

I'm trying to avoid having to loop through every chars with a bunch of if-else logic.

Note: I'm using these regex expression in Java (Kotlin) and using "containsMatchIn" method to match the source expression to actual text.

Comment: I'd write or use a parser--having a stack is helpful when you can have arbitrarily nested parens because regexes can't store state. If you do use regex, you'll need a recursive one. It's a bit harder than the dupe target suggests because you'll need to omit escaped substrings like `\(` and other edge cases but it should give you a starting point.

Comment: @ggorlen Recusion seemed promicing until I found out it's not available in Java. :-(

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use PERL-compatible regular expressions, not standard Java ones, for they don't support recursion. Try this: `\(\?<?[!=](?<r>[^()]|\(\g<r>+\))+\)`.

- `\(\?<?[!=]` and `\)` are the beginning and end of an assertion,
- `(?<r>[^()]|\(\g<r>+\))+` is a regular expression for a string with balanced parentheses,
- `[^()]|\(\g<r>+\)` is either a non-parenthesis, or a string with balanced parentheses (called recursively) within parentheses,
- `\g<r>` is a recursive call to the previous rule.

Saved: https://regex101.com/r/mjMoyz/1.

Comment: Do you know any active/recent perl-compatible regex libraries for java? (I'm developping in Android Studio so I don't have much of a choice about using java)

Comment: You might find these answers helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37890800/6632736 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/27616512/6632736.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution... had to do a little out of the box thinking :-)

The following code did the trick, basically behaving like PERL's comment group construct `(?#...)`:

Using string replacement:

> expression = expression.replace("(?<!", "(?<!*").replace("(?<=",
> "(?<=|").replace("(?!", "(?!*").replace("(?=", "(?=|")

Or using regex replacement:

> expression =
> Regex("""((?<?!)""").replace(Regex("""((?<?=)""").replace(expression,
> "$1|"), "$1_")